# Anchor link isn't working in an email on mobile devices

Tags: html, mobile, anchor, html-email

I have an anchor tag in one part of the page that is meant to jump to another section within the email body. 
Somehow the anchor tag isn't functioning as it is on desktop and the email in a mobile browser.

`<a href="isi2></a>` isn't jumping to this ->
 `<a name="isi2"></a>`

I've copied and pasted the HTML below to provide more context.

```
            <td>
              <a href="#isi2">
              <img
                alt=""
                style="
                  border: 0;
                  display: block;
                  width: 100%;
                  height: auto;
                "
                src="#"
              />
            </a>
          </td>

     <tr>
    <td width="640" height="auto" bgcolor="#ededed">
      <a name="isi2"></a>
      <img
        alt=""
        style="border: 0; display: block; width: 100%; height: auto;"
        src="#"
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the name attribute in your `a` tag, try this instead:

```
<a href="#isi2"></a> to -> <a name="isi2" id="isi2"></a>
```

Comment: That's not working for me. The name attribute was working for this HTML except for when it's opened on a mobile device.

Comment: check the href, its not close <a href="#isi2></a> must be like that <a href="#isi2"></a>

Comment: It's closed the first a tag is wrapped around an image. Could you provide further clarification on what you mean, please?

Comment: mistake fix: <a href="#isi2"></a> to -> <a name="isi2" id="isi2"></a> ; explanation: id attribute doesn't have # tag.

Comment: adding the id attribute to my destination a tag doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor links are not supported on all email clients. You can get more details here: https://www.caniemail.com/features/html-anchor-links/